# How to control when socket connection request is sent to backend from client?

Tags: vue.js, socket.io

Using `vue-socket.io` my frontend is currently firing off a Socket.io connection request to my backend when my app is being built initially or every time I refresh the page. This is problematic for me as my page gets initially built at the landing page. This means that it is sending a socket request without the proper data since the user hasn't logged in yet. Once the user logs in I am unable to send another socket connection request.

`socket.js` (`plugins` folder) **FRONTEND**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import store from "../store";
import SocketIO from "socket.io-client";
import VueSocketIO from "vue-socket.io";

Vue.use(
  new VueSocketIO({
    debug: true,
    connection: SocketIO("http://localhost:3000", {
      query: { token: store.state.token }
    }),
    vuex: {
      store,
      actionPrefix: "SOCKET_",
      mutationPrefix: "SOCKET_"
    }
  })
);
```

socket.js (`controllers` folder) **BACKEND**

```
io.use(function (socket, next) {
    console.log('Token ' + socket.handshake.query.token);
    if (socket.handshake.query && socket.handshake.query.token) {
      jwt.verify(socket.handshake.query.token, 'THIS IS SUPPOSED TO BE PRIVATE', function (err, decoded) {
        if (err) return next(new Error('Authentication error'));
        socket.decoded = decoded;
        next();
      });
    } else {
      next(new Error('Authentication error'));
    }
  })
    .on('connection', function (socket) {
      socket.on('JOIN_ROOM', (room) => {
        socket.join(room);
      });
      // CourseQuestions Page
      socket.on('POST_QUESTION', (data) => {
```

I am looking for a way to programmatically send off the socket connection request AGAIN from the frontend once the user has logged in preferable using `vue-socket.io`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass `{ autoConnect: false }` as options into `new VueSocketIO()`.
Something like this:

```js
new VueSocketIO(..., { autoConnect: false }, ...)
```

And then, when you want to open the connection just call `this.$socket.open()`.

[GitHub issue](https://github.com/MetinSeylan/Vue-Socket.io/issues/109). and check out that [comment](https://github.com/MetinSeylan/Vue-Socket.io/issues/137#issuecomment-500778472).